# When would Presenter update model in MVP

Tags: design-patterns, mvp

I was reading about MVP, and in case of supervisor controller, Presenter can update the model and View can listen to those changes.

I am not able to understand when would presenter update a model. Ideally presenter acts on request from view. And if view is requesting to something, why can't presenter return the result to view. Instead of going through different route where presenter updates the model and view listen to that and act accordingly.

And even if one view is updating and other view is interested in this event, then also view can raise event which other view can listen to.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi, did you get the answer you expected?? :))

Answer (score 0):

In most simple form **MVP** is this kind of analogy.

- Assume there's a student (A) from whom teacher ask a presentation about some topic. A is a good speaker but he doesn't know how to prepare a presentation.
- So he asks his friend (B) to prepare him a presentation. B accepts that. But B doesn't know any fact about that topic.
- So B asks his fiend C to point up some facts about the topic.
- So C accepts and C points some facts to B. So B makes the presentation and passes to A. Then A delivers it.

In that story

***C- Model*** | ***A- View*** | ***B- Presenter***.

So in your questions

> And if view is requesting to something, why can't presenter return the
>   result to view ?

Simply ***Presenter*** is not responsible to accommodate business logic. It's the duty of ***Model***. This is what we called ***Decoupling***.

> And even if one view is updating and other view is interested in this
>   event, then also view can raise event which other view can listen to.

Please note that in **MVP**, ***View*** and ***Presenter*** has ***1-1 relationship***.

Hope you understood the points. :))